# RxJava: Open session, perform query and close session

Tags: rx-java

I'm newbie in Rx and I'm trying to create an Observable that:

1. Requests for a token
2. Creates a request with this token and perform a query to a third-party service
3. Closes session using token

I have this:

```
public Observable<List<City>> getCities() {

    authService.requestToken() //return Observable<String>
        .concatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<? extends List<City>>>() {
          @Override
          public Observable<? extends List<City>> call(String token) {
              CitiesRequest request = new CitiesRequest(token);
              return soapClient.consume(request).map(new CityResponseParseFunc());                    }
        })
        //Here, I need close the session using the token. Maybe with doOnCompleted?
}
```

I don't know if it is right and don't know how continue. Note that I need that the method returns `Observable<List<City>>`. Is this possible?

Thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `requestToken()` only emits a single value you can switch `concatMap` for `flatMap` and use this overloaded version of it:

```java
authService.requestToken() //return Observable<String>
        .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<? extends List<City>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends List<Integer>> call(String token) {
                CitiesRequest request = new CitiesRequest(token);
                return soapClient.consume(request).map(new CityResponseParseFunc());
            }
        }, new Func2<String, List<City>, List<City>>() {
            @Override
            public List<City> call(String token, List<City> cities) {
                authService.closeSession(token)
                return cities; /*close session with token*/
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if `authService.closeSession(token)` returns `Observable<Boolean>`?. How should the `call` method where I close the session?

Comment: @bigdestroyer hmm, does the result of `closeSession` affect your intention to pass `cities` downstream? I mean if you listen to `closeSession`, what you expect to do with its emitted `Boolean` item?

Comment: mm you're right. I think I don't need that boolean value, so everything ok Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use the [`using`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#using(rx.functions.Func0,%20rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Action1)) operator. It takes 3 functions as parameter:

1. A `Func0<Resource>` that creates/obtains the resource with which to work (here a token).
2. A `Func1<Resource, Observable<T>>` that creates the `Observable<T>` that'll work with the resource (here our Observable of lists of cities).
3. A dispose function, `Action1<Resource>` that will dispose of the resource at the end of the lifecycle of the `Observable<T>`.

Since your `authService` seems to return an `Observable<String>`, it can make usage of the `using` operator a little more complicated, especially for the dispose function (need to cache the resource `Observable<String>` so that dispose function subscribing to it won't regenerate a token). The other way around that is to get the token synchronously.

Something like this:

```
Observable<List<City>> cities = Observable.using(
    //resource creation function
    () -> authService.requestToken().toBlocking().single(),
    //observable creation function
    token -> soapClient.consume(new CitiesRequest(token)).map(new CitiesResponseParseFunc())),
    //resource disposal function
    token -> authService.closeSession(token)
);
```